# babel-plugin-react-css-modules is not matching styles with styleName

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules, babel-plugin-react-css-modules

**Issue**

I am trying to use [babel-plugin-react-css-modules](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#runtime-stylename-resolution) in my React project for better performance as opposed to *React CSS Modules*.

However, the styles are being not applied correctly.

**Cause**

The version in `<style>` tag is wrapped with weird hypen, for example:

- In the `<style>` tag: `-components-Foo-___Foo__foo___1fcIZ-`
- On the DOM
  element class name: `components-Foo-___Foo__foo___1fcIZ`

> Even if we are using the same `localIdentName`, the generated results
>   are different from selectors in css and className on DOM element.
>
> (Note: In babel-plugin-react-css-modules, the `localIdentName` is
>   `[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]` as hard-coded in
>   `options.generateScopedName`)

Any idea why there is a hypen-wrapper?

Comment: Raised by others in the source repo but no luck yet
https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules/issues/132

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the solution myself after some struggling.

### Cause

This is due to a quirk of `css-loader`: if there are double quotes around `localIdentName` option, it will wrap the generated class name with hyphens.

### Working Examples

So instead of doing this in webpack config:

```
{
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader?sourceMap',
        'css-loader?modules="true"&importLoaders="1"&localIdentName="[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"',
        'sass-loader?sourceMap',
    ],
},
```

Do this:

```
{
    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
    use: [
        'style-loader?sourceMap',
        'css-loader?modules="true"&importLoaders="1"&localIdentName=[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
        'sass-loader?sourceMap',
    ],
},
```

Or event better if you are using Webpack 2+

```
{
        test: /\.(scss|sass$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,    
              modules: true,
              sourceMap: true,
              localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          },
          'sass-loader'
        ]
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue and it was because I didn't have the line:

localIdentName: '[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'